# Image doesn't show up in java swing when i click my Jtable

Tags: java, sql, image, swing, jtable

I want to search image and show it into `JLabel` (the label's name is `tampilFoto`) and then save it as long blob into database and it works, and when I want to show image in a label when the user clicks in a `JTable` (the table's name is `tblBalon`), but the image doesn't show up, and there's no error show up when clicking the label.

Here is the code to upload the image:

```
private void tblFotoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String sumberFile = f.getAbsolutePath();
    sumberFoto.setText(sumberFile);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(sumberFile);
    Image image = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(tampilFoto.getWidth(), tampilFoto.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    tampilFoto.setIcon(icon);
}
```

Here is the code to show the image into label when clicking the table:

```
private void tblBalonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    try {
        int row = tblBalon.getSelectedRow();
        nim.setText(tblBalon.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
        nama.setText(tblBalon.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
        fakultas.setSelectedItem(tblBalon.getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
        prodi.setSelectedItem(tblBalon.getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
        noUrut.setSelectedItem(tblBalon.getValueAt(row, 5).toString());
        calon.setSelectedItem(tblBalon.getValueAt(row, 6).toString());
        visi.setText(tblBalon.getValueAt(row, 7).toString());
        misi.setText(tblBalon.getValueAt(row, 8).toString());
        sumberFoto.setText(tblBalon.getValueAt(row, 9).toString());
        String tampil = "SELECT * FROM databalon WHERE idBalon='"+row+"';";
        ResultSet rst = stk.executeQuery(tampil);
        byte[] image =null;
        if(rst.next()){
            Blob img = rst.getBlob("foto");
            image = img.getBytes(1,(int)img.length());
            BufferedImage imag = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(image));
            ImageIcon ft = new ImageIcon(imag);
            tampilFoto.setIcon(RImage(ft));
        }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PanitiaDataBalon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
    this.btnHapus.setEnabled(true);
    this.btnUbah.setEnabled(true);
    this.btnTambah.setEnabled(false);
    this.btnBatal.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You should also consider using `ResultSet#getBinaryStream`

Comment: `img.getBytes(1,(int)img.length());` - Shouldn't that start at `0` and not `1`. I'd also check the result result if `img.length`

Comment: @MadProgrammer so i must make may code become like this `img.getBinaryStream(1,(int)img.length());`?

Comment: You really should read the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream(int))